SwiftData model context delete not working
In SwiftData I can't get delete(model:where:includeSubclasses:) method to work. In the code example below I would expect both the School and its students to be deleted because of the cascade delete rule.
What I am doing wrong?
import XCTest
import SwiftData

@Model
class School {
    var name: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Student.school)
    var students: [Student]

    init(name: String, students: [Student]) {
        self.name = name
        self.students = students
    }
}

@Model
class Student {
    var name: String
    var school: School

    init(name: String, school: School) {
        self.name = name
        self.school = school
    }
}

final class Test: XCTestCase {
    func testScenario() throws {
        let modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for:
            School.self,
            Student.self
        )
        
        let context = ModelContext(modelContainer)
        context.autosaveEnabled = false
        
        let school = School(name: "school", students: [])
        context.insert(school)
        
        let student1 = Student(name: "1", school: school)
        let student2 = Student(name: "2", school: school)
        context.insert(student1)
        context.insert(student2)
        
        XCTAssertEqual(try! context.fetchCount(FetchDescriptor<School>()), 1)
        XCTAssertEqual(try! context.fetchCount(FetchDescriptor<Student>()), 2)
        
        try context.delete(model: School.self)
        
        XCTAssertEqual(try! context.fetchCount(FetchDescriptor<School>()), 0) // XCTAssertEqual failed: ("1") is not equal to ("0")
        XCTAssertEqual(try! context.fetchCount(FetchDescriptor<Student>()), 0) // XCTAssertEqual failed: ("2") is not equal to ("0")
    }
}


The problem isn't with the delete method alone but the state of the objects in your ModelContext.
In your test code you never call save() on your ModelContext object so objects you have created and inserted only exists in memory (in your context object).
Then the delete method you use is ment for deleting multiple objects so it will, as I understand it, only act on persisted objects and ignore any pending changes. That is it will ignore objects that only exists in memory and only delete those stored to disk.
So the solution then is to call save() after the last insert
//...
context.insert(student2)

try! context.save()
//...

Another solution is to use another delete method that deletes a specific object.
context.delete(school)

(this function will work without calling save() first since it uses the objects that the context object is holding)
