SwiftData inverse relationship not updating
Given the code below the students array on the school is not being updated. Why?
Since the relationship is explicit and non-optional I would expect this to work.
import XCTest
import SwiftData

@Model
class School {
    var name: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Student.school)
    var students: [Student]

    init(name: String, students: [Student]) {
        self.name = name
        self.students = students
    }
}

@Model
class Student {
    var name: String
    var school: School

    init(name: String, school: School) {
        self.name = name
        self.school = school
    }
}

final class Test: XCTestCase {
    func testScenario() throws {
        let modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for:
            School.self,
            Student.self
        )
        
        let context = ModelContext(modelContainer)
        context.autosaveEnabled = false
        
        let school = School(name: "school", students: [])
        context.insert(school)
        
        let student1 = Student(name: "1", school: school)
        let student2 = Student(name: "2", school: school)
        context.insert(student1)
        context.insert(student2)
        
        XCTAssertEqual(school.students.count, 2) // XCTAssertEqual failed: ("0") is not equal to ("2")
    }
}

Versions

iOS deployment target: 17.5
Xcode version: 15.4
Swift version: 5.10


I can't reproduce this. In your previous question the same test didn't fail.

It's better to only use an in memory container for unit tests if that could be an issue here. Create a ModelConfiguration for this, ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true), and then use an initialiser for ModelContainer that takes such a configuration

Thank you for your response @Joakim Danielson. It sounds strange that you are not able to reproduce it. It fails repeatedly when I run it. In my previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/78962118/9253300)  I did not test if the school had the students, I only tested that the students existed.

Yes of course, I see it now that it's not the same test. Still strange that I can't reproduce.

Are you using the same versions as I am?

No, I am using Xcode 16 so this could be a reason although I am running the test for iOS 17.5

I tried running the tests on Xcode 16.0 beta 6, both iOS 17 and iOS 18, but I get the same result. The test still fails.

Are you only running this test or a suite of tests?

Only this test.
